# An odd DOM cache/refreshing issue with LI items and jQuery

Tags: jquery, caching, refresh, html-lists

I have a dynamically injected `<li>` items with the first item gets marked with ".current" class. I also have "next" button in the DOM that loads the next item from the item with the ".current" class in the list. However, when i repopulate the list dynamically, the "next" button would load the every other item in the list. If i repopulate the list again, the next button would load the every 3rd item in the list. List is populated through $.ajax and is a json data type. Everytime i repopulate, I remove all the list items as below:

```
 $('#playlist').children().remove();
```

The next button finds the next item as below:

```
 $('#playlist ul').find(".current").nextAll().first().children('a');
```

**Any idea/suggestion as to why there would be inconsistency on loading the "next item" in the list?** Clearly, it has to do with the repopulating the list also.. I'm setting "cache":false in my $.ajax call that populates the list...

When this inconsistency occurs, the behavior seems as such that next item is starting off from item (with class ".current") from the previously loaded list..

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unA6h/7/    (not the full code I have but the portion that's giving me the headache; list gets populated from ajax call..json etc..)

Comment: Just a quick question... Why are you using `.nextAll().first()` over `.next()`? They both should do the same thing.

Comment: Can you recreate that issue in a fiddle ??

Comment: Or provide some HTML that would allow us to recreate it in a fiddle?

Comment: Previously loaded: Do you mean hitting F5?  Can you paste your code for populating the list as well as the resulting HTML so we can see what's going on?  More context is needed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Right, but in this case there is no selector. That selector (that i'm assuming is missing) + the html will probably be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Kevin, heh, you're right. Comment retracted :)

Comment: here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unA6h/7/

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `.nextAll()` on the anchor tag which doesn't have any siblings, so `.nextAll()` doesn't get any elements. you need to add `.parent()` before `.nextAll()`. I also made a small optimization below, no point in getting teh id and selecting by id when you already have the element.

```
var next_item = $('#playlist ul').find('.current').parent().nextAll('li[role="normal_item"]').first().children('a');
setItemAsCurrent(next_item);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unA6h/16/

Comment: Thanks @Kevin B However, that wasn't the issue though... So if i now repopulate the list with different data, the "next" button doesn't load the items one after the other. Everytime i repopulate, that many times the number of items it skips in the list is the issue...please help! i'm desparate.. been trying to figure this one out for 2 days now

Comment: your current code relies on an element having the `.current` class, are you placing that class where it needs to be in the new markup you are adding?

Comment: should this kind of tasks not be reliant on class or DOM element? I sometimes wonder if the best practice is to register this sort of things with variables... Anyway, I updated the code so that it dynamically loads another list. It is working as i want on fiddle but it doesn't in my original code. Difference is that my list is loaded through $ajax in the original code. So i wonder what in $.ajax would result this behavior..

Comment: If you've noticed, li items with role="not_normal_item" are skipped in the next function... In my original code, it skips the items x number of times i repopulated the list..if that makes sense..

Comment: add console.log("worky") in the event. how many times is it happening per click?

Comment: That means your event is being bound multiple times.

Comment: i see.. Of course running $('#playlist').children().remove(); removes the tags from the DOM.. i suppose it doesn't clear the event cache.. Is there a such thing as reseting/clearing event cache?

Comment: Remvoing an element will remove it's events, however i suspect you aren't removing the next button. Try only running the event binding code once rather than every time you load more elements.

Comment: Behavior sort of suggests that the javascript still thinks it's working with the same list even though the list has been repopulated..If there is a way to let the javascript to know the list has been updated...any idea/suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with it though. if `loadNext` is running 4 times when you click once, that event has been bound 4 times rather than once.

Comment: That is right.. I'm not removing the next button. can you give an example on how to run the event binding code once? should i create variable toggle that my script checks on?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19384/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-still-questioning)